# Go regex to match all lines that don't start with timestamp

Tags: regex, go, regex-negation

Can anybody explain what the correct Java regex is to match all lines that don't start with timestamp `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`?

I am trying to use `^(^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `^(^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})` pattern matches a string starting with the pattern you defined (the `^` here just matches the start of a string).

In Go lang, the regex engine does not support lookarounds, and thus it is difficult to create a readable regex that would do the required job.

I suggest you remove all lines that match your pattern

```
(?m)\s*^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*
```

([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/oaYqfT/3)) and then split the result with line breaks to get the lines that did not match the pattern.

Comment: thanks for your explanation but I am getting error regarding  unsupported Perl syntax `(?!`. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Java `java.util.regex`? What is the regex flavor?

Comment: Oh it's for Go, my bad

Comment: @jack_017: It is a really bad "bad" since Go does not support *any* lookarounds. See the updated answer with a workaround suggestion. I do not mean there is no way to use a regex here, but it will be a veeeery long unreadable regex.